# How to customize labels on x/y axis in pimage()

Tags: r, axis-labels

I wonder how I can customize the labels on x/y axis to the row/column names in the distance matrix I used in permutation image plot. Thanks!

```
library("seriation")
dm <- data.frame(matrix(1:100, nrow = 10))
colnames(dm) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
rownames(dm) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
dt <- as.dist(dm)
ser <- seriate(dt, method = "MDS")
pimage(dt, ser, colorkey=TRUE)
```

I want to use "a", "b", "c" as the labels on both axis.

p.s. The cell labels were properly displayed when the number of cells is small (e.g., 9 cells), but the labels were hidden when there are more cells, like the example above.

Comment: Do you want to change the order of the plot elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the values in the object `ser`:

```
ser[[1]] <- sort(ser[[1]])
```

The plot:

```
pimage(dt, ser, colorkey = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sven, I just realized that I need to rephrase/reconsider my question :-p